# Recognize "congruent" dates

Tags: android, date, math

I'm working on an Android App and I need to know, given to dates and a number, if the second date is congruent with the first one in module the number.
This is, for example, if the first date is 13, that if summing/subtracting 'K' times 13 days to the first date, you can get the second date, being K an integer.

It would be easy to do this with a for loop, but it wont be efficient, so finally I have code this two funtions:

```
private static Date removeTime(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 50);
    return cal.getTime();
}

public static boolean isImportantDay(Date date, Date selectedDate, int period, int numDays) {
    date = removeTime(date);
    selectedDate = removeTime(selectedDate);
    long milDate = date.getTime();
    long milSelDate = selectedDate.getTime();
    long temp = milSelDate - milDate;
    long dayIntervalMs = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(period);
    Log.i("DATE", String.valueOf(selectedDate));

    if(temp% dayIntervalMs == 0){
        Log.i("SI", String.valueOf(temp));
        return true;
    }
    Log.i("NO", String.valueOf(temp));
    return false;
}
```

Whis this, using the milliseconds representation of the dates, I should be able to know if they are "congruent" or not. It works perfectly on the Android Studio Emulator, but when I try to run it on my OnePlus One it just works with some dates.

I use removeTime() to prevent the millisecons having different time.

Does somebody knows where is the error on the code?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get from Calendar.getInstance() will vary with the configured locale and timezone, which might be different for your device and the emulator.  In certain time zones, your code might break if the date span crosses a change in timezone (like a switch to daylight savings time).

The way to fix this is in the removeTime method create a Calendar for a timezone without timezones (like UTC) and set it with the date from the Calendar for the local timezone, and get the milliseconds from the non-timezone calendar.  Then your calendar day will be correct for your local timezone, and the number of milliseconds between the days will be what you expect regardless of DST changes in your local timezone.

Comment: Ok, I have tried to apply your fix, but I have not understand all  your advice and it still doesn´t work.
I have created a new calendar and set it to UTC timezone, then I set the date of the non-timezone calendar with the date from the first one, and I return the date from the second calendar. This is what I have added, and I return `cal2.getTime();`

`Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        cal2.setTime(cal.getTime());

        return cal2.getTime();`

Comment: @Javierd98 -- Get the month, day, year from cal and set them on cal2.  Set a constant hour, minute, second on cal2.